# Spring Boot Jpastreamer - com.speedment.jpastreamer.application.JPAStreamer can not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, javabeans, jpastreamer

I have a problem to run my Spring Boot with the usage of Jpastreamer.
I cannot solve the bean issue related with Jpastreamer.

Here is the PersonService shown below

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PersonService {

    private final JPAStreamer jpaStreamer;
    private final PersonRepository personRepository;

    ... 
}
```

I got this issue shown below when I run the application.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.springboot.jpastreamer.service.PersonService required a bean of type 'com.speedment.jpastreamer.application.JPAStreamer' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.speedment.jpastreamer.application.JPAStreamer' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is the repo shown below

[Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/jpastreamer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After defining `JPAStreamer` as a `bean` in `JPAStreamerConfig` shown below, the issue disappeared.

```
import com.speedment.jpastreamer.application.JPAStreamer;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JPAStreamerConfig {

    private final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Bean
    public JPAStreamer jpaStreamer() {
        return JPAStreamer.of(entityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```